# Extract user name from perl script

Tags: perl

I want to extract user name, executing a perl script, within a script itself.

I am executing `whoami` linux command from perl as follows and it works pretty well.

```
my $whoami = `whoami`;
chomp $whoami;
print $whoami;
```

My intention is to get away from calling system commands from perl script. Therefore I am looking for **Perl only** solution. I was wondering if there is any CPAN module available which can extract system information.

Your suggestions in this regards will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
perl -le 'print scalar getpwuid $<'
```

Answer (score 3):

You should probably take at look at the hash **%ENV**. It contains useful information about the environment where your script is run.

One example (in windows) to get the username would be:

```
perl -E "say $ENV{'USERNAME'}"
```

For bash substitute `USERNAME` for either `LOGNAME` or `USER`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I am using linux env and it gives error saying *ENV: Undefined variable.*

Answer (score 3):

Perl have direct mapping to system `getpw*` functions.

> These routines are the same as their counterparts in the system C
>   library.  In list context, the return values from the various get
>   routines are as follows:
>
> ($name,$passwd,$uid,$gid,
>      $quota,$comment,$gcos,$dir,$shell,$expire) = getpw*

-- from `perldoc -f getpwuid`.

Use `getpwuid` with `$<` as argument (which, according to `perldoc perlvar` is "The real uid of this process", and also available as `$REAL_USER_ID` and `$UID`) and get first returned value.